# How do I make sure MySQL in docker container is initialized using scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:5.7

COPY ./create_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./insert_types.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d
RUN  chmod -R 755 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 1307
```

Output of logs for the mysql container:

```
docker logs 8742      
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.20-1.1.2
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.20-1.1.2
```

That seems... short.

(fake passwords below btw)

Contents of the init folder in the container; following commands are from inside the container:

```
bash-4.2# ls -alh docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov  3 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov  3 21:02 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  268 Nov  3 16:01 create_db.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  911 Nov  1 18:08 create_tables.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  363 Nov  1 18:08 insert_types.sql
```

Contents of the create script:

```
bash-4.2# cat docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql 
SELECT 'creating database duplicate_identifiers' as 'logging';
create database duplicate_identifiers;
create user 'deduplicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ajsdfhaosidufjlkjljlui08!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON events.* TO 'deduplicator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The root password is set:

```
bash-4.2# echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
whiskey
```

But I can't connect using that:

```
bash-4.2# mysql -u root -p            
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Mysql is present but the database was never created.

```
bash-4.2# mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. ...

mysql> use duplicate_identifiers;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'duplicate_identifiers'
```

I'm stumped. How do I get MySQL to use the initialization scripts to run and create my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L150-L157) isn't fully executed, that might be because of the `if` conditions that are wrapping `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` scripts calls.

```
if [ "$1" = 'mysqld' ]; then
  if [ ! -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
```

So test and print those values first, to see if it is normal that the `for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do` is not called at all.